# Angular app creates 500 error code when running it locally

Tags: asp.net, angular, sql-server-2008

I have an Angular app which gives me a 500 error code when run it locally and try to create an account. I run the application on my laptop, the database is on my laptop too.

The database is using Windows Authentication, and the user role membership is `db_owner`, the application can retrieve data from the database, but when I try to create a user or sign in as a user I get 500 error code.

This is the error I get when I try to sign in as a user: [image]

and this is the error message I get when I try to create a user:[image]

Not sure how to resolve this issue, or what is causing this issue. Can someone point me in the right direction?

This is what my proxy.config.js look like:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
    {
        context: [
            "/api",
            "/connect"
        ],
        target: "http://localhost:5000/",
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true
    }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Comment: You need to allow your API's to be accessed from localhost.

Comment: Add more comments about how my proxy.config.js look like

Comment: You should be using `https://` not `http://` as many web-browser features (like CORS, Cookies, etc) [work best in secure environments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts).

Comment: You won't be able to diagnose or solve a **server-side** problem (i.e. HTTP 500) by looking at client-side JS. What are the server-logs? Is anything printed to `stderr`? What do you see in your NPM/AngularCLI console/terminal window - and are you using your debugger? (And why are you using SQL Server 2008? It's obsolete and unsupported...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by having the wrong connection string. Check the web.config to see if the connection string is correct or check the connected service in Visual Studio.